# Loops and output

Tags: arrays, loops, sas, do-loops, sas-studio

I am trying to get a bit handy with my loop and output statements, currently I have a loan which amortizes like such:

```
data have;
input Payment2017 Payment2018 Payment2019 Payment2020;
datalines;

100 10 10 10;

run;
```

I'm trying to create a maturity and re-issuance profile that looks like this, I will explain the logic when I submit my current code:

```
data want;
input;
P2017 P2018 P2019 P2020 F1 F2 F3 MP2017 MP2018 MP2019 MP2020 NI2017 NI2018 NI2019 NI2020;
datalines;

100 10 10 10 0.1 0.1 0.1 100 10 10 10 0 0 0 0
100 10 10 10 0.1 0.1 0.1 0 10 1 1 0 10 0 0
100 10 10 10 0.1 0.1 0.1 0 0 11 1.1 0 0 11 0
100 10 10 10 0.1 0.1 0.1 0 0 0 12.1 0 0 0 12.1
;
run;
```

so the logic is that:

Payment2017 = the balance at the start of the year
Payment2018 - 2020 = the amount paid each period
F1-F3 is the fraction of the loan that is being paid each period.

MP2017-MP2020 is the amount of the loan that is paid back - essentially it is

```
mp(i) = p(i) *f(i)
```

NI2017-NI2020 is the amount that is newly issued if you assume that each time I pay off a bit of the loan , it is added back onto the loan. so the current code which I am using looks like this but i'm having some issues with the ouput and loops.

```
        data want;
        set have;

        array MaturityProfile(4) MaturityProfile&StartDate-MaturityProfile&EndDate;  
        array NewIssuance(4) NewIssuance&StartDate - NewIssuance&EndDate;
        array p(4) payment&StartDate-payment&EndDate;
        array fraction(3); * track constant fraction determined at start of profile;

            MaturityProfile(1) = P(1);

            do i = 1 to 3;

            fraction(i) = p(i+1) / p(1);

            end;

            iter=2;
            do j = 1 to 2;
            do i = iter to 4;

            MaturityProfile(i) = P(j) * Fraction(i-j);
            newissuance(i) = MaturityProfile(i);
            end;
            output;
            iter=iter+1;
            end;
            output;

            *MaturityProfile(4) = ( P(3) + MaturityProfile(2) ) * Fraction(1);


            *output;

            drop i;
            drop j;
            drop iter;

            run;
```

I'm trying to find a way of for the first two rows, keeping it how it outputs currently but the third row needs the sum of the column for the second row ( or the newissuance2019) and then multiply that by fraction 1

so basically the output to look like the table I've put in the data want step.

TIA.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fix this by doing:

```
data want;
    set have;

    array MaturityProfile(4) MaturityProfile&StartDate-MaturityProfile&EndDate;  
    array NewIssuance(4) NewIssuance&StartDate - NewIssuance&EndDate;
    array p(4) payment&StartDate-payment&EndDate;
    array fraction(3); * track constant fraction determined at start of profile;
    array Total(4) Total1-Total4;

        MaturityProfile(1) = P(1);

        do i = 1 to 3;

        fraction(i) = p(i+1) / p(1);

        end;

        iter=2;
        do j = 1 to 2;
        do i = iter to 4;

        MaturityProfile(i) = P(j) * Fraction(i-j);
        Total(i)=MaturityProfile(i) + P(i);
        end;
        output;
        iter=iter+1;
        end;

        MaturityProfile(4) = Total(3) * Fraction(1);


        output;

        drop i;
        drop j;
        drop iter;

        run;
```